# Angularjs component not working in knockoutjs template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, knockout.js, components

I'm trying to launch an AngularJS component from knockout template.
Something like below in the html.

```
<!-- ko if:something -->
    <my-angular-component attr1= "text1">
      <span data-bind="text: text1"></span> & <span data-bind="text: text2"></span>
    </my-angular-component>
<!--/ko -->
```

I need to get the data from the knockout scope to angular scope. But whenever I do so, my angular component is not triggered.
Any ideas?

Comment: "*I'm trying to launch an AngularJS component from knockout template*" Why?

Comment: My angular application is being built on top of an existing Knockout app. Due to time constraints we have configured both to work together

Comment: @VarunG I'd have to say, That does not sounds like it will be time efficient.

Comment: This is actually a really bad idea, but if you want to run an Angular component from a KnockoutJS app... you'd need to bootstrap the angular app ngApp or angular.bootstrap and then include the component in the HTML.  The angular compiler should then interpret the angular component appropriately.  I don't know what Knockout will do, but it might work.

Comment: You guys are completely right. It's also a performance overload as well. Unfortunately, I have no say whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

well first off this seems like a really bad idea. if it is an existing knockout application why are you trying to add angular? knockout also has components so you can just use the knockout component. otherwise  I'm sure angularjs and knockoutjs are going to bang into each other.

Anyway.  It seemed to work for visible binding but not for an if binding.  here is the plunkr.  https://plnkr.co/edit/AvWH2JEF2DEUIWkYBQNy?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp" class="no-js">
<head>
    <title>My AngularJS App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <p>show component: <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: something" /></p>
    <div ng-app="myApp"> 
   <div data-bind="visible: something">
        <hello-world name="world"> </hello-world>
  </div>

    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
    function viewModel() {
    var self = this;
     this.something = ko.observable(true);
   }
      var vm = new viewModel();

(function($) {
  ko.applyBindings(vm); //bind the knockout model
})(jQuery);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

and the angular component.

```
(function(){
angular.module("myApp", [])
  .component("helloWorld",{
      template: "Hello {{vm.name}}!",
      bindings: { name: '@' },
      controller: ('helloWorldController',helloWorldController),
      controllerAs: 'vm'
  })
  function helloWorldController(){
     /* jshint validthis: true */
        var vm = this;
  }
})();
```

Comment: I totally understand what you are trying to say. but I have no say whatsoever in this. Regarding this answer, The prob is a particular feature was developed in Knockout. After that, a new  parent feature is to be developed, The app is an AngularJS app, and inside it knockout and I just want to reuse an existing component